# Convert multiple string to dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matrix, split

There are three strings that I want to convert.

```py
 row='A;B;C'

 col='aaa,bbb,ccc;aaa,bbb,abc;aaa,bbb,ccc'

 val='99,80,90;100,100,100;90,90,90'
```

I wanna convert `String` to `Dataframe` or `Matrix` in Python.

```py
   aaa  bbb   ccc   abc

A  99   80    90    NaN

B  100  100   NaN   100

C  90   90    90    NaN
```

How to convert the above strings or any other strings to `Dataframe`?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick with https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

You have some inconsistent delimiters that I have replaced with `,`

```
row='A,B,C' 
col='aaa,bbb,ccc,aaa,bbb,abc,aaa,bbb,ccc' 
val='99,80,90,100,100,100,90,90,90'
buffer = ""
buffer += row + "\n" + col+ "\n"+val
pandas.read_csv(buffer)
```

Comment: I tried 
`data=pd.read_csv(StringIO(buffer))` 
Therefore I get                            
`
A    B    C
aaa bbb ccc aaa bbb abc  aaa  bbb  ccc
99  80  90  100 100 100   90   90   90 ` 
how can I get dataframe format what I aksed?

Comment: It should return a dataframe

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
def create_frame(row_str, col_str, val_str,
                 record_delim=';', field_delim=','):
    out = zip(row_str.split(record_delim),
              col_str.split(record_delim),
              val_str.split(record_delim))

    df = pd.DataFrame({i: dict(zip(c.split(field_delim),
                                   v.split(field_delim)))
                       for i, c, v in out})
    return df.T

# Example
row='A;B;C'
col='aaa,bbb,ccc;aaa,bbb,abc;aaa,bbb,ccc'
val='99,80,90;100,100,100;90,90,90'

df = create_frame(row, col, val)
print(df)
```

[out]

```
   aaa  bbb  ccc  abc
A   99   80   90  NaN
B  100  100  NaN  100
C   90   90   90  NaN
```